# 2016 15-inch MacBook Pro speaker makes buzzing sound

Tags: macbook-pro, speakers

I have a MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2016). I have noticed that when I play any sound through the speaker, the speaker starts buzzing. The buzz stops after ~1 minute without playing any sound. When I put the sound on mute, the speaker won't play the audio out loud but the buzzing still happens. The volume of the buzzing sound stays the same when I adjust the volume of the laptop, even on mute. I'm pretty sure it is the speaker because I can also hear the sound when the fan is on max.

I have tried restarting the computer several time, resetting SMC and PRAM, plugging in power adapter and removing it. But those didn't made any progress on fixing it. Any more ideas before I take the machine to the Apple Store?

P.S. Many people reports that it is an outdated Bootcamp driver issue, but I never installed Windows on my MacBook. I am running the latest version of macOS.

EDIT:

When I plug in headphone, the buzz stops. It starts buzzing again when I unplugged the headphone.

Comment: What happens if you plug in headphones?

Comment: @Tetsujin updated question

Comment: & is the buzz then in the headphones, or are both silent? Also, is it in one speaker/ear, or both?

Comment: @Tetsujin The buzz doesn't happen in the earphone (I tested with the Apple EarPod), it happens on both of the speaker.

Comment: Ah, OK. Then I don't have a simple test. It would have to be hands-on. i'd take it to Apple.

Comment: Can you give an update on how you solved the problem? Was it a faulty MacBook?

Comment: @FrederickSquid I also tested my friend’s 2016 MBP, it doesn’t make this sound. One thing to note is that my friend purchased his laptop a few months after mine so that might be it? It might be a faulty machine.